# GlusterFS how to failover (smartly) if a mounted Server is failed?

Tags: mount, nat, failover, glusterfs

In GlusterFS, lets say i have 2 Nodes (Servers) on a Volume. Lets say the volume info is something like this:

```
Volume Name: volume-www

Brick1: gluster-server-01:/volume-www/brick
Brick2: gluster-server-02:/volume-www/brick
```

From the Client, as we know, we have to mount the volume `volume-www` by mounting from one Server. Like:

```
mount -t glusterfs  gluster-server-01:/volume-www  /var/www
```

I still feel there's a choke point since i am connecting to that `gluster-server-01` only.

- What if it is FAILED?

Ofcourse I can manually mount from another healthy Server again. But is there a smarter way (industrial approach) to solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you are doing this:

```
mount -t glusterfs  gluster-server-01:/volume-www  /var/www
```

You are initially connecting to one of the nodes that make up the Gluster volume, but the Gluster Native Client (which is FUSE-based) receives information about the other nodes from `gluster-server-01`.  Since the client now knows about the other nodes it can gracefully handle a failover scenario.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @SamHolmes It's on the gluster website: https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Setting%20Up%20Clients/#mounting-volumes

Comment: what will happen when gluster-server-01 is not available during the mount (for example after a reboot of client)?

Comment: @DánielKis there you go: https://gluster.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Administrator-Guide/Consul/

Answer (score 3):

[OpenUserX03's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229899/282348) is not quite accurate.

When a client connects to a Gluster server node, it receives information about all the nodes. After that, it starts communicating with multiple nodes simultaneously. So when one node dies, it does not "failover", it just lose that node but keep the communication going on with the others:

In their documented note:

> The server specified in the mount command is only used to fetch the
>   gluster configuration volfile describing the volume name.
>   Subsequently, the client will communicate directly with the servers
>   mentioned in the volfile (which might not even include the one used
>   for mount).

Comment: So in simpler words, the Client will automatically connect to another online/available Node (from the Pool), which is the great solution by itself? Which is the good thing, we shall say?

Comment: @夏期劇場 Yes. I think this logic is the foundation of GlusterFS's design. But it also depends on how the Gluster volume is setup. For example, if volume is simply a "distributed" type, then the live node won't have the file you need, which is on the failing node only. OP implies the file is wholly replicated on the second node.

Comment: My experiments don't agree with this. I have a replica:3 volume in a cluster with 6 nodes. When I mount with FUSE, the moment just one of those nodes dies (a random, but specific one) I get an error: Transport endpoint not connected. It sounds exactly as if the client is connected to one node and one only and then when it dies, the client dies as well. Maybe I'm missing some kind of option or...?

Answer (score -2):

You can use two way below:

1. Use backupvolfile options fstab

> server1_name:/media /media glusterfs
>   defaults,_netdev,backupvolfile-server=server2_name,log-level=WARNING,log-file=/var/log/gluster.log
>   0 0

2. create data file /etc/datastore.vol example

`volume mymedia-client-0
    type protocol/client
    option clnt-lk-version 1
    option volfile-checksum 0
    option volfile-key /mymedia
    option client-version 3.8.12
    option process-uuid server01.vn-7565-2017/10/03-02
    option fops-version 1298437
    option ping-timeout 42
    option remote-host 192.168.10.79
    option remote-subvolume /data01/brick
    option transport-type socket
    option transport.address-family inet
    option send-gids true end-volume   volume mymedia-client-1
    type protocol/client
    option clnt-lk-version 1
    option volfile-checksum 0
    option volfile-key /mymedia
    option client-version 3.8.12
    option process-uuid server01.vn-7565-2017/10/03-02
    option fops-version 1298437
    option ping-timeout 42
    option remote-host 192.168.10.80
    option remote-subvolume /data01/brick
    option transport-type socket
    option transport.address-family inet
    option send-gids true end-volume   volume mymedia-replicate-0
    type cluster/replicate
    subvolumes mymedia-client-0 mymedia-client-1 end-volume   volume mymedia-client-2
    type protocol/client
    option ping-timeout 42
    option remote-host 192.168.10.81
    option remote-subvolume /data01/brick
    option transport-type socket
    option transport.address-family inet
    option send-gids true end-volume   volume mymedia-client-3
    type protocol/client
    option ping-timeout 42
    option remote-host 192.168.10.82
    option remote-subvolume /data01/brick
    option transport-type socket
    option transport.address-family inet
    option send-gids true end-volume   volume mymedia-replicate-1
    type cluster/replicate
    subvolumes mymedia-client-2 mymedia-client-3 end-volume   volume mymedia-dht
    type cluster/distribute
    option lock-migration off
    subvolumes mymedia-replicate-0 mymedia-replicate-1 end-volume   volume mymedia-write-behind
    type performance/write-behind
    subvolumes mymedia-dht end-volume   volume mymedia-read-ahead
    type performance/read-ahead
    subvolumes mymedia-write-behind end-volume   volume mymedia-readdir-ahead
    type performance/readdir-ahead
    subvolumes mymedia-read-ahead end-volume   volume mymedia-io-cache
    type performance/io-cache
    subvolumes mymedia-readdir-ahead end-volume   volume mymedia-quick-read
    type performance/quick-read
    subvolumes mymedia-io-cache end-volume   volume mymedia-open-behind
    type performance/open-behind
    subvolumes mymedia-quick-read end-volume   volume mymedia-md-cache
    type performance/md-cache
    subvolumes mymedia-open-behind end-volume   volume mymedia
    type debug/io-stats
    option log-level INFO
    option latency-measurement off
    option count-fop-hits off
    subvolumes mymedia-md-cache end-volume   volume meta-autoload
    type meta
    subvolumes mymedia end-volume`

vs fstab content:

```
/etc/datastore.vol /media glusterfs defaults,_netdev,log-level=WARNING,log-file=/var/log/gluster.log 0 0
```